# Getting error while executing Hive query in windows azure

Tags: hive

After connecting to windows azure through powershells I am executing hive query just to show the tables. But I am getting following error.

```
Invoke-Hive : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At line:1 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-Hive -Query @"
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-AzureHDInsightHiveJob], StorageException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.HDInsi
   ght.Cmdlet.PSCmdlets.InvokeHiveCmdlet
```

Could you please guide me what to do ? I am using windows 7 OS Home premium , service pack 1

Comment: How are you running your query? Did you define a `queryString`, create a Hive job definition and then submit  it to the cluster?

Comment: Sorry, so you are using `powershell`. How are you invoking?

Comment: after successfully connected to azure cluster through powershell I have submitted this query to check the tables only. $response = Invoke-Hive -Query @"
show tables;
"@
Write-Host $response

Comment: I am able to resolve this issue. This issue is related with system clock (laptop clock). I had to re-set my laptop clock as per my current time zone then I re-log in through powershell to execute hive query and that went fine. Thanks Visakh..for showing interest to resolve it.

Comment: it would be great if you post the resolution as an answer . It might help someone else in future...

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve this issue. This issue is related with system clock (laptop clock). I had to re-set my laptop clock as per my current time zone then I re-login through powershell to execute hive query and that went fine.